# Using SQL to compute average daily unique usage

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table "stats", which is a list of entries for each login into a website. Each entry has a "*userId*" string, a "*loginTime*" timestamp and other fields. There can be more than one entry for each user - **one for each login** that he makes. I want to write a query that will calculate the average of unique daily logins over, say, 30 days.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: I have "SELECT DISTINCT `userID` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`loginTime`) = CURDATE()" that will show unique users for today. I can replace CURDATE() with any date, and i can COUNT() the results, but I don't know how to go through the last 30 days with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

/*
This should give you one row for each date and unique visits on that date
*/

SELECT DATE(loginTime) LoginDate, COUNT(userID) UserCount

FROM stats

WHERE DATE(loginTime) BETWEEN [start date] AND [end date]

GROUP BY DATE(logintime), userID

**Note: It will be more helpful if you can provide some sample data with the result you are looking for.**

Answer (score 0):

i'm probably wrong but if you did: `select count(distinct userid) from stats where logintime between start of :day and end of day` for `day` in each of those 30 days fetched those 30 counts (which could be pre-calculated cached (as you probably don't have users logging in at past times)) and them just average them in the programing language that your executing the query from

i read http://unganisha.org/home/pages/Generating_Sequences_With_SQL/index.html while looking and thought if you had a table of say the numbers 0 to 30 lets name it offsets for this example:

```
select avg(userstoday)
from (select count(userid) as userstoday, day
      from stats join offsets on (stats.logintime=(current_day)-offsets.day)
      group by day)
```

and as i noted, the userstoday value could be pre-calculated and stored in a table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, eventually I used:
SELECT SUM(  `uniqueUsers` ) / 30 AS DAU
FROM (

SELECT DATE(  `loginTime` ) AS DATE, COUNT( DISTINCT  `userID` ) AS uniqueUsers
FROM  `user_requests` 
WHERE DATE(  `loginTime` ) > DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 30 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY DATE(  `loginTime` )
) AS  `daily_users`

I use a SUM and divide by 30 instead of average, because on some days I may not have any logins and I want to account for that. But on any daily heavy-traffic website simply using AVG will give the same results